# How do I scroll downward but have an object appear to be rising?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I stumbled upon Robby Leonardi's website and once I got to the end of the website where the character hops in the balloon I was intrigued. I cannot figure out how to make the webpage appear to be rising while scrolling downwards. I've been looking all over for how to do something of that sort just for test purposes but cannot find for the life of me a tutorial or any information on it. If you know of a tutorial or can just point me in the general direction it would be greatly appreciated.

`http://www.rleonardi.com/interactive-resume/`

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to use a container div with fixed positioning that is the width and height of the window. Everything that needs to move is contained within the container div. Underneath that you can have another div that will be the width and height of the "world" so that the page can be scrolled. Using javascript you can then change the positioning of the elements within the container in response to a scroll event. An extremely rudimentary demo might be:

https://codepen.io/thebrengun/pen/jaOQOj

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="balloon"></div>
  <div id="sky"></div>
</div>
<div id="spacer"></div>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var sky = document.getElementById('sky');
  var spacer = document.getElementById('spacer')
  drawClouds(sky);
  sky.style.top = -1 * sky.offsetHeight + window.innerHeight + 'px';
  spacer.style.height = sky.offsetHeight + 'px';
  document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll(sky));
});

function handleScroll(sky) {
  return function(e) {
    var scrolled = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    sky.style.top = -1 * sky.offsetHeight + window.innerHeight + scrolled + 'px';
  };
}

function drawClouds(canvas) {
    const cloudFactory = (x, y) => {
      var cloud = document.createElement('div');
      cloud.className = 'cloud';
      cloud.setAttribute('style', `left: ${x}px; top: ${y}px`);
      return cloud;
    };

    for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      canvas.append(cloudFactory(i % 2 === 0 ? 45 : 450, 0));
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#container {
  background: blue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}

#sky {
  position: relative;
}

.cloud {
  position: relative;
  width: 292px;
  height: 184px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='292' height='184'><path fill='#ffffff' d=' M 79.72 49.60 C 86.00 37.29 98.57 29.01 111.96 26.42 C 124.27 24.11 137.53 26.15 148.18 32.90 C 158.08 38.78 165.39 48.87 167.65 60.20 C 176.20 57.90 185.14 56.01 194.00 57.73 C 206.08 59.59 217.92 66.01 224.37 76.66 C 227.51 81.54 228.85 87.33 229.23 93.06 C 237.59 93.33 246.22 95.10 253.04 100.19 C 256.69 103.13 259.87 107.67 258.91 112.59 C 257.95 118.43 252.78 122.38 247.78 124.82 C 235.27 130.43 220.23 130.09 207.98 123.93 C 199.33 127.88 189.76 129.43 180.30 128.57 C 173.70 139.92 161.70 147.65 148.86 149.93 C 133.10 153.26 116.06 148.15 104.42 137.08 C 92.98 143.04 78.96 143.87 66.97 139.04 C 57.75 135.41 49.70 128.00 46.60 118.43 C 43.87 109.95 45.81 100.29 51.30 93.32 C 57.38 85.18 67.10 80.44 76.99 78.89 C 74.38 69.20 74.87 58.52 79.72 49.60 Z'/></svg>");
/* 
Cloud svg from (I removed the blue bg):   https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Cloud%2C_blue_background.svg
*/
}

#balloon {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 64 64' enable-background='new 0 0 64 64'><path d='m52 22.5c0 11.3-8.8 24.4-19.8 24.4-10.9 0-19.8-13-19.8-24.4.1-11.3 8.9-20.5 19.8-20.5 11 0 19.8 9.2 19.8 20.5' fill='#ed4c5c'/><g fill='#94989b'><path d='m31.5 49.1c0 0 0-.1 0-.1 0 0 0 .1 0 .1'/><path d='m31.6 49.2c-.1 0-.1-.1 0 0'/></g><path d='m33 49.2h-1.5c0 1.8-.4 3.9-1.9 5.2-2.1 1.8-4.9.7-7.4.6-3-.1-5.6 1.2-7.7 3.2-.8.7-1.6 1.7-2.3 2.5-.8.9.3 1.9 1.1 1 1.5-1.8 2.6-3.1 4.6-4.3 2.6-1.5 5-.7 7.8-.6 3.2.2 6.1-1.4 7-4.7.2-.7.3-2 .3-2.9' fill='#b2c1c0'/><path d='m31.5 49c0-.1 0 0 0 0' fill='#94989b'/><path d='m30.8 48c1 0 1.9 0 2.9 0 .9 0 .9-1.3 0-1.3-1 0-1.9 0-2.9 0-.9.1-.9 1.3 0 1.3' fill='#b2c1c0'/><path d='m30.1 50c1.4 0 2.9 0 4.3 0 1.4 0 1.4-1.9 0-1.9-1.4 0-2.9 0-4.3 0-1.4-.1-1.4 1.9 0 1.9' fill='#ed4c5c'/></svg>");
/* 
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Emojione_1F388.svg
*/
}
```